# Possible to use keras “flow_from_directory” with “.mat” files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I have built a CNN to predict lymph node positivity (has cancer or not). Right now to  load the data I have a self defined function that loads a batch of data and feeds it to the model for training.

Instead of loading batches I would love to use the `flow_from_directory` method. The problem I have is that my data are saved as arrays [#, rows, width, height, PET or CT] not images (that would later be converted to arrays). Example [0,:,:,:,0] is volume sized 48x48x32 from a ct image.

If I try to use `flow_from_directory` I get 0 images with 3 classes which I expected since '.mat' is not a recognized file (https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/362fe9f8daf556151328eb5d02bd5ae638c653b8/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L1868). Interestingly it doesnt raise any errors but I am indefinitely stuck on 1/150 epochs.  I am going to see if I can write my own `flow_from_directory`. Not sure if someone has run across this problem and could give my pointers.

**Illustrating how data is combined**

```
for fname in fnames:
     data = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(dir_in_train, fname))['roi_patch']
     data_PET =  scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(dir_in_train_PET, fname))['roi_patch']
     train_combo[0,:,:,:,0]=data/4.0950
     train_combo[0,:,:,:,1]=data_PET/32.1959
     train_combo[0,:,:,:,:].shape
     train_combo = np.zeros((1, 48, 48, 32, 2))

     scipy.io.savemat(fname, {fname: train_combo})
```

This will create a file ex '1.mat' that has CT data and PET data in one area

Then I have code changing it into npy files.

**Example of data generator I already have**

```
# load training data
    def load_train_data_batch_generator(self, batch_size=32, rows_in=48, cols_in=48,  zs_in=32, 
                                        channels_in=2, num_classes=3, 
                                        dir_in_train=None, dir_out_train=None):

        # dir_in_train = main_dir + '/test_CT_PET_combo'

        fnames = ['{}.mat'.format(i) for i in range(1,len(os.listdir(dir_in_train))+1)]

        y_train = np.zeros((batch_size, num_classes))
        x_train = np.zeros((batch_size, rows_in, cols_in, zs_in, channels_in))

        while True:
            count = 0
            for fname in np.random.choice(fnames, batch_size, replace=False):

                data_label = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(dir_out_train, fname))['output']

                # changing one hot encoding to integer
                integer_label = np.argmax(data_label[0], axis=0)
                y_train[count,:] = data_label

                # Loading train ct w/ c and pet/ct combo that will be saved into new directory
                train_combo = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(dir_in_train, fname))[fname]
                x_train[count,:,:,:,:] = train_combo

                count += 1

            yield(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: If u can , why don't you just create the images and save them in format that flow accepts , depending on your task , define the images as numpy arrays and save them with imageio or any other similar library so you don't have recreate the images again and again

Comment: This will be a great next step! Currently I have been trying to convert the '.mat' files into '.npy' files because I saw "NumpyArrayIterator".  But just to be clear your suggestion is to convert to numpy array then use imageio to save into .jpg format for example.  My only concern (maybe not even valid) is that I will be using imageio to save two volumes/"images" at once. One corresponding to the PET volume and the other corresponding to the CT volume.

Comment: Can you please expand on your issue, if it is that you can save images at once then there's no issue if it is something else then can you please expand on it .as a side note use png and jpg , jpg is a lossy image format and for such small image sizes it really starts affecting performance

Comment: I added some code to give a better idea of how my data is stored (it was given to me as separate .mat files for CT volumes and PET volumes). My concern is whether  or not having multiple 3D images in one array/tensor makes saving as png difficult/impossible

Comment: Do you want to do some data Augmentation? if not, why don't just create a simple custom generator?

Comment: I have included what I have for a data generator already. What I would like is to use the equivalent of Keras' "flow_from_directory". Unfortunately it just seems to takes   data in form {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'bmp', 'ppm'}. I would like it to take array data directly. So I would either like to learn how to make a custom "flow_from_directory" function or be able to alter keras' "flow from directory" function to accept arrays directly (this seems harder haha).